# Scrollbar does not take proper background color

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

See: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fXJLv/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="element">some content</div>
        <div class="element">some content</div>
        <div class="element">some content</div>
        <div class="element">some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: green;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
.content {
    height: 1000px;
}
.element {
    background: blue;
}
.element:nth-child(even) {
    background: yellow;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder, ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.1s ease;
}
```

As you can see in demo, blue and yellow (.element) is properly rendered, and scrollbar is OVER it, but how to set scrollbar's background to blue (and yellow).
It has to work only in Chrome (It will be chrome app).

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to apply the blue color background for scroll area.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{background-color:blue;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXJLv/14/)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the scrollbar to be striped as well.

Comment: you mean to say you want texture of color in the background??

Comment: you can use background image instead of background-color.

Comment: That isn't possible either, because my "rows" (.element) have dynamic height.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fXJLv/18/ check this fiddle. I have just applied some background in the scroll area.

Comment: I know that I can apply background property to scrollbar. But I need that scrollbar to take background from blue and yellow elements. I need it to look like scrollbar is hovering ABOVE the element. Something like [this](http://learnboost.github.io/antiscroll/). But without javascript.